# Can't bind org-insert-todo-heading to S-M-return?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm new to Emacs and having trouble getting the [default key binding](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-basics.html#TODO-basics) working for the Emacs Org mode command `org-insert-todo-heading`.

Per `describe-function` for `org-insert-todo-heading`, I see the following:

`It is bound to <M-S-return>, ESC <S-return>, C-c C-x M.`

The first element of this indicates to me that "meta+shift+return" should add a new TODO heading. Alas, this is not happening. All I get is a measly newline.

Any thoughts as to how this can be rectified?

I realize this is probably a more general Emacs+iTerm+OS X key binding issue than Org mode, but that's the context I'm working in.

I'm using OS X and Emacs 25.2.1 (installed via Homebrew)

Comment: Does the second choice `ESC <S-return>` work? Are you doing this in a graphical environment or in console mode (or perhaps doing `emacs -nw` in a terminal window)?

Answer (score 1):

In terminal emacs `M-S-RET` is actually `M-RET`.
Terminals interpret key sequences differently: http://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html

The alternative is using this binding in terminal: `C-x C-m M` (https://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-Keys.html)

You could also map `org-insert-todo-heading` to a different binding.
E.g. Add to your init the following line `(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f1>") 'org-insert-todo-heading)`